# Parallel Processing( multiple consumers ) on MYSQL Change Data Capture with Apache Kafka

Tags: mysql, database, parallel-processing, apache-kafka, change-data-capture

I have been researching on how to implement a system to capture change in a MySQL database. One of the examples I have looked at was LinkedIn's use of DataBus ( http://www.slideshare.net/SunilNagaraj1/databus-eventbrite2013 ) , and also other folks in different places using Apache Kafka.

It seems to be implied in all the above projects that you have multiple consumers working in parallel  when receiving data from the MySQL binlog. The consumers are supposed to replay all those INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands they receive on another MySQL database that is supposed to be a mirror of the original source DB.

But wouldn't this mean that those INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands might be interpreted out of order when executed on the target mirror MySQL database?

For example, if in the binlog, you had these two statements that are in the shown order :

```
DELETE FROM stats;
INSERT INTO stats VALUES(....);
```

and then the first statement goes to Consumer 1, and then the second goes to Consumer 2, but Consumer 2 executes first followed by Consumer 1, wouldn't that cause a loss of data?

Therefore, it seemed like the only way around it for now is to have one topic, one partition and one single consumer(or consumer group) in the case of using Apache Kafka.

I was wondering what everyone's thoughts are about this. I understand this is using statement-based changes in the MySQL binlog. Would it be different if we used row-based changes instead?

Thanks
IS

Comment: BTW, https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/